# ErrorHandler -- want it to complete and re-raise an exception

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask

So I have an error handler like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(error):
    utils.send_error_to_slack()
    return render('500'), 500
```

One of the great features of the Google App Engine environment is, if an exception happens, it gets tracked in StackDriver.

Problem is, by using this error handler, I catch all exceptions in my app and nothing makes it up to StackDriver.

So what I want to do is have this error handler, which provides a nice result for our end users, and then re-raise the original exception. Though I'm not quite sure how to do this as the function ends with 'return' and I can't raise before the return -- and I can't raise after it. I know I have to wrap this function somehow, just not sure how.

I did see the "PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS" option, but activating it doesn't allow the nice-end-user-error-page to be rendered.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe try `webapp2.abort(500)` instead of the return statement?

Comment: Where are you looking? Just deployed a simple app using errorhandler and the error still appears in the logs of Stackdriver.